# Express in terms of $r$, $\theta$ the following equations

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Book: Introduction to Complex Analysis, H. A. Priestley

This may be stupid question, but this exercise doesnt make much sense to me

Exercise 1.3.(i)-(v): Express in terms of $r$, $\theta$ the following equations, where $z=re^{i\theta}$:

(i) $|z^2| = 4$

(ii) $|z^2 - 1| = 1$

(iii) $ arg(2z) = \frac{2\pi}{3} $

Now, my attempt doesnt make sense anyway, $\theta$ or $r$ vanishes or.... what even are the solutions? Help <3[image]

Comment: Please show your attempts first.

Comment: uploaded a attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, your method seems unnecessarily complicated. Much simpler to go $|z^2| = 4 \implies |z|^2 = 4 \implies r^2 = 4 \implies r = 2$. Note that the magnitude is non-negative, so you should not have the negative root.

For the second one, you omitted a couple steps. Let's look at the manipulation of the LHS: $|z^2 - 1| = \sqrt{|(z^2 - 1)\overline{(z^2-1)}|} = \sqrt{|(z^2 - 1)(\overline{z^2}-1)|}$ (justified by $\overline{w - x} = \overline w - \overline x$), following which you squared both LHS and RHS to get your equation.

You can simplify your final answer to $r = \sqrt 2 |\cos 2\theta|$ (that's an absolute value sign on the RHS), but it's OK as you left it.

The last one is very easy. The argument of a complex number is not affected by a real multiplier, so $arg(2z) = arg(z)$. You can immediately conclude $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{3}$. $r$ doesn't enter into the expression at all.

(Please note the correction in the final one, I made a major error initially).

Comment: Thank you sir for regaining my confidence! Yes, I might have overcomplicated my evaluation @Deepak

Comment: @Muhy I am so sorry, I made a major error in the last one (I was rushing). I have edited it. Please acknowledge this.

Comment: Ah I see! arg(nz)=arg(z).  No worries man ;) thanks for the help @Deepak